# ElasticSearch MasterNotDiscoveredException

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I've setup an elasticsearch cluster in kuberentes, but I'm getting the error "MasterNotDiscoveredException".  I'm not really sure even where to begin debugging this error as there does not appear to be anything really useful in the logs of any of the nodes:

```
│ elasticsearch {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-06-15T00:44:17,226Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "logging-ek", "node.name": "logging-ek-es-master-0", "message": "path: /_bulk, params: {}",                                                             │
│ elasticsearch "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized, SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];",                                                                                                  │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:179) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                                             │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction$BulkOperation.handleBlockExceptions(TransportBulkAction.java:635) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                       │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction$BulkOperation.doRun(TransportBulkAction.java:481) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                                       │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                                                   │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction$BulkOperation$2.onTimeout(TransportBulkAction.java:669) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                                 │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                         │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                      │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                                 │
│ elasticsearch "at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                              │
│ elasticsearch "at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ elasticsearch "at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ elasticsearch "at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│ elasticsearch "Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException",                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│ elasticsearch "\tat org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                    │
│ elasticsearch "\tat org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                       │
│ elasticsearch "\tat org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                    │
│ elasticsearch "\tat org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                               │
│ elasticsearch "\tat org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.1.jar:7.17.1]",                                                                                                                            │
│ elasticsearch "\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│ elasticsearch "\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│ elasticsearch "\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]"] }
```

is pretty much the only logs i've ever seen.

It does appear that the cluster sees all of my master nodes:

```
elasticsearch {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-06-15T00:45:41,915Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "logging-ek", "node.name": "logging-ek-es-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joine │
│ d a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is empty on this node: have discovered [{logging-ek-es-master-0}{fHLQrvLsTJ6UvR_clSaxfg}{iLoGrnWSTpiZxq59z7I5zA}{10.42.64.4}{10.42.64.4:9300}{mr}, {logging-ek-es-master-1}{EwF8WLIgSF6Q1Q46_51VlA}{wz5rg74iThicJdtzXZg29g}{ │
│ 10.42.240.8}{10.42.240.8:9300}{mr}, {logging-ek-es-master-2}{jtrThk_USA2jUcJYoIHQdg}{HMvZ_dUfTM-Ar4ROeIOJlw}{10.42.0.5}{10.42.0.5:9300}{mr}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300, 127.0.0.1:9301, 127.0.0.1:9302, 127.0.0.1:9303, 127.0.0.1:9304, 127.0.0.1:9305, [::1]:9300, [::1]: │
│ 9301, [::1]:9302, [::1]:9303, [::1]:9304, [::1]:9305, 10.42.0.5:9300, 10.42.240.8:9300] from hosts providers and [{logging-ek-es-master-0}{fHLQrvLsTJ6UvR_clSaxfg}{iLoGrnWSTpiZxq59z7I5zA}{10.42.64.4}{10.42.64.4:9300}{mr}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version  │
│ 0 in term 0" }
```

and I've verified that they can in fact reach each other through the network.  Is there anything else or anywhere else I need to look for errors?  I installed elasticsearch via elasticoperator.

Answer (score 0):

Start doing curl to the 9300 port. Make sure you get a valid response going both ways.

Also make sure your MTU is set right or this can happen as well. It's a network problem most of the time.

Comment: Can you expand on "MTU is set right".  What's the "right" value?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).